# removeClass not working jQuery

Tags: jquery

I wanted to create something when cliked to the button the background should change one image to another image such as `toggle`. However i used `removeClass` and `addClass` but not working. Here is my code.

**html**

```
<button>click</button>
```

**jquery**

```
var button = $('button').eq(0);
var html = $('html');
button.on('click', function(){

  if(html.hasClass == 'have'){
    alert('do');
    html.css({
    background : 'url(http://img.pixland.uz/u2080f129653m.jpg)'
    }).removeClass('have');
  }else{
    html.css({
    background : 'url(http://img.pixland.uz/u13301f281573m.jpg)'
    }).addClass('have');
  }

});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/wvbhg/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check the syntax of [hasClass](http://api.jquery.com/hasclass/):

```js
if (html.hasClass('have')) {
    //
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`hasClass` should `hasClass('have')`:

```
if(html.hasClass('have'));
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/wvbhg/5/)**

Comment: How does this make a difference?

Answer (score 1):

syntax should be

```
if(html.hasClass('have')){ ... }
```